# Very slow site load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I made a PHP script which requests information from a MySQL table.  If it's correct, it does something, but this script is very slow because there are many rows where it is not correct.
Here is the script:

```
$everypost = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(asd) FROM asd;");
$everypost = mysql_fetch_array($everypost);
$id = $everypost[0];
while ($id > 0 && $i < $var2) {
    $id = $id - 1;
    $tulajid = $context['user']['id'];
    $posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd WHERE asd='$id' AND owner='$var' GROUP BY(asd);");
    $prow = mysql_fetch_array($posts);
    if(isset($prow['asd'])) {//If it's correct, so the user is the owner
        $i++;
    }
}
```

My problem is that it checks every post and not only the user's posts.
Is there some solution to make it faster?
If I remove `AND owner ='$var'` from the $posts query, it is very fast.

```
CREATE TABLE `asd` ( 
  `asd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `id_member` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `score` smallint(2) NOT NULL, 
  `owner` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `log_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_msg`,`id_member`), 
  KEY id_member (`id_member`), 
  KEY owner (`owner`), 
  KEY owner_2 (`owner`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SOLUTED

Comment: Do you have the `owner` column indexed? Problem solved.

Comment: I indexed it and it's still slow.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement indicates that the `asd` table doesn't even *have* an `owner` column ...

Comment: id_msg = asd | id_poster = owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still slow.
The id_msg = asd and the id_poster = owner.

Answer (score 2):

That means you need to review your database design. You probably don't have, and thus need, and index on your `owner` column.

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: It is still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here isnt necessarily the DB design, but the way you are going about querying the information. You pulling the most recent something in one query, then you are looping down and issuing a query for each iteration of the loop. That sir, is insane. You can do this in way fewer queries by using the correct conditions.

Without more information from your schema i woudl assume you could do something like:

`SELECT a.* FROM asd a WHERE a.owner = ? ORDER BY a.asd DESC`

That would get you all instances of an `asd` tuple where the `owner` is a certain value (you would replace the `?` with your value), ordered by the `asd`, highest to lowest. Im not sure if thats what you want, and if you can post more information about the table and the variables in the PHP i can probably give you a better answer, but regardless of the data youre trying to get im pretty sure there is a much more efficient way of doing it than what you are doing now.

Comment: So, how should I do it?

Comment: I was jsut about to get to that... what are `$var` and `$var2` and can you show us the schema of the `asd` table?

Comment: $var is the owner of the thing. $var2 is the maximum amount of thing which are showed on one page. ( This is not the full code. ) The asd table:  id_msg (=asd) | id_member | score | id_poster (=owner) | log_time

Comment: And is that he same as `$context['user']['id']` or a diffrent user? and what is `var2`? Can you post the schema for the table, just run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE asd` and post it in your initial question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `asd` (
 `id_msg` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `id_member` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `score` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
 `id_poster` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `log_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_msg`,`id_member`),
 KEY `id_member` (`id_member`),
 KEY `id_poster` (`id_poster`),
 KEY `id_poster_2` (`id_poster`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

And $var = $context['user']['id']

Comment: ok so i dont see a column called `asd` in the `asd` table... whats that all about?

Comment: I edited my 3. comment to this post, I think you didn't see it, sorry:
"$var is the owner of the thing. $var2 is the maximum amount of thing which are showed on one page. ( This is not the full code. ) The asd table: id_msg (=asd) | id_member | score | id_poster (=owner) | log_time"